# Como meter loops dentro de un switch

Tags: javascript

Buenas estory tratando de hacer un menu que me pida tres opciones y en cada opcion ejecute en una un for , otra un while, y en otra un do while. El problema es que no consigo hacer que me imprima el while por pantalla, adjunto el codigo que  llevo hecho hasta ahora( he puesto document write para saber si imprimia algo).

```
var grade = 'Opciones';
            document.write("Entering switch block<br />");
            switch (grade) {
               case 1:
                var count = 0;
                while (count < 10) {
                   document.write("Current Count : " + count + "<br />");
                   count++;
                }
               break;
            
               case 'B': document.write("Pretty good<br />");
               break;
            
               case 'C': document.write("Passed<br />");
               break;
            
               default:  document.write("Unknown grade<br />")
            }
            document.write("Exiting switch block");
         //-->
```

Comment: esta evaluando el caso 'opciones' , inicializa grade por ejemplo con 1 y vas a ver que funciona

Comment: Gracias me sirvio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te mencionaron, estas evaluando el `switch` con la variable `grade` que contiene `opciones`, por lo que como no se encuentra en ningún `case`, por lo que te manda el  valor por default.

En este caso, puedes leer desde un `prompt` para que puedas escoger el caso, y a su vez usar el `case '1'`, para que no tengas problemas.

```js
var grade = prompt('Enter option:');
            document.write("Entering switch block<br />");
            switch (grade) {
               case '1':
                var count = 0;
                while (count < 10) {
                   document.write("Current Count : " + count + "<br />");
                   count++;
                }
               break;
            
               case 'B': document.write("Pretty good<br />");
               break;
            
               case 'C': document.write("Passed<br />");
               break;
            
               default:  document.write("Unknown grade<br />")
            }
            document.write("Exiting switch block");
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvio